# TeXLive 2010 - manual uninstall on Windows

Tags: installing, texlive, windows

Accidentally, after executing the "remove program" command in the `control panel/add remove programs/Tex Live 2010`, I deleted the installation folder under `C:\`, too, manually.

But the program is not removed entirely, since I got error messages about version conflict with existing TL 2010 installation while trying to set up TL 2011.

```
Installing TeX Live 2011 from: http://www.bitlib.net/mirror/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet
Platform: win32 => 'Windows'
Distribution: net  (downloading)
Using URL: http://www.bitlib.net/mirror/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet
Directory for temporary files: C:/DOCUME~1/User/LOCALS~1/Temp
Loading http://www.bitlib.net/mirror/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
'""C:\Documents' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\install-tl\install-tl-20110630\install-tl: The TeX Live versions of the local in
stallation
and the repository being accessed are not compatible:
      local: 2011
 repository: 2010
Perhaps you need to use a different CTAN mirror?
Press any key to continue . . .
```

So, I don't know how to manually remove my TL 2010 installation. Anyone literate about references and tutorials which files are to be removed, where they are located, which registry keys to delete and what else to do to remove TL 2010 completely?

Comment: Seeing the exact error messages you got would help a lot. Maybe it's the local `TEXMF` folder? No idea, where it is located on Windows.

Comment: Herbert already explained what's the problem.  I would further suggest that you avoid paths with spaces and it's generally better to wait for released version, unless you are willing to deal with potential breakage during the testing phase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you downloaded the 2011 pretest installation program but then choosed a repository which has only 2010. Take one of these repositories:

http://tug.org/texlive/mirmon/

and then run:

```
install-tl -repository <one of the pretest hosts>
```